# Where can I find good statistics quizzes?

Tags: teaching

Introductory, advanced, and even obscure, please.

Mostly to test myself. I like to make sure I know what the heck I'm talking about :)

Thanks

Comment: community wiki?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote a post compiling links of  Practice Questions for Statistics in Psychology (Undergraduate Level).
http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2009/12/practice-questions-for-statistics-in.html

The questions would fall into the introductory category.

Answer (score 5):

Tests and thousands of sample questions are available on the ARTIST ("Assessment Resource Tools for Improving Statistical Thinking") site, https://app.gen.umn.edu/artist/tests/index.html .  Most are appropriate for an intro stats course.